# How to handler HTTP Request with # character in URL

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

My customer sent one HTTP request with URL http://example.com/callback#id_token=data
Now I need handle this request and get data of "id_token".
Please help me handle this request using Java web project.
I tried with servlet but not get data of "id_token"
My servlet is below

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>callback</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.admin.controller.CallbackServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>callback</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/callback</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the hash `#` being encoded? Is the request submitted via a browser? If yes, the hash already has a different meaning where it is only accessible via javascript.

Comment: My customer perform send redirect url http://example.com/callback#id_token=data in their libary. Now we need handle this request and process data "id_token".

Comment: You can't access the hash value at the server, you have to use javascript to handle it.

Comment: Hi Adder, Please help me one sample code using javascript. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unless url-encoded, the hash `#id_token=data` usually ends up in `document.location.hash` on the client side.

```
console.log(document.location.hash);//#id_token=data
var hash = document.location.hash;
var split = hash.split('=');
console.log(split[0]);//#id_token
console.log(split[1]);//data
```

You can usually access the console with F12, tab "console".